# Adding/multiplying two infinity results in infinity, while subtracting/dividing two infinity results in NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting console logs of two Infinity by adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing them.

While adding/multiplying two infinities, i get inifinity,
but while substracting/divinding them, i get NaN(not a number).
why this is happening ? (ran in nodejs).
the type of Infinity is a number, so why subtracting or dividing them is not resulting in a number ?

```
console.log(Infinity+Infinity) //gives Infinity
console.log(Infinity*Infinity) //gives Infinity
console.log(Infinity-Infinity) //gives NaN
console.log(Infinity/Infinity) //gives NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Infinity subtracted from infinity and infinity divided by infinity don't have specific values as results. `∞ / ∞` is not equal to 1, and `∞ - ∞` is not equal to 0. This is specific to the mathematics behind them and not JavaScript.

JavaScript `NaN` value as a result indicates that an operation was incorrect. And `NaN` is actually a number.

Comment: Was in the middle of editing the answer. Thanks for pointing at that.